# Why "invalid sender" (-32000) when trying to deploy an Ethereum smart contract from node script?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, truffle

Trying to deploy my smart contract to the rinkeby network but I am receiving this error message
`{ code: -32000, message: 'invalid sender' }`.

I tried deploying my contract via Remix and it worked fine but I am a bit lost on why I am receiving this error.

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider"); // "^1.2.4"
const Web3 = require("web3"); // "^1.3.4"
const compiledFactory = require("./build/factory.json");
const abi = compiledFactory.abi;
const bytecode = compiledFactory.evm.bytecode.object;

const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
  mnemonic: {
    phrase:
      "twelve word mnemonic phrase twelve word mnemonic phrase twelve word mnemonic phrase",
  },
  providerOrUrl: "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/12345678",
});
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log("Attempting to deploy from account", accounts[0]);
  try {
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
      .deploy({ data: bytecode })
      .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });
    console.log("Contract deployed to", result.options.address);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};

deploy();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work. Problem is, the transaction has to be signed before sending it. Here is the updated deploy function.

```js
const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const deploymentAccount = accounts[0];
  const privateKey = provider.wallets[
    deploymentAccount.toLowerCase()
  ].privateKey.toString("hex");

  console.log("Attempting to deploy from account", deploymentAccount);

  try {
    let contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
      .deploy({
        data: bytecode,
        arguments: [],
      })
      .encodeABI();

    let transactionObject = {
      gas: 4000000,
      data: contract,
      from: deploymentAccount,
      // chainId: 3,
    };

    let signedTransactionObject = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
      transactionObject,
      "0x" + privateKey
    );

    let result = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
      signedTransactionObject.rawTransaction
    );
    console.log("Contract deployed to", result.contractAddress);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  process.exit(1);
};
```